# Get avatar of an user in discord.js that doesn't share the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a small problem with my bot. For developing my bot, I made a new dev-bot which shares the same code as my normal bot, but has it's own token.
However, I ran into a small issue while developing.

I use this code, to get someones' avatar:

```
client.users.get(event.user.uid).avatarURL
```

This works fine on my normal but, however on my Dev-Bot I get this error message:

```
Error getting documents TypeError: Cannot read property 'AvatarURL' of undefined
```

I think it's due to the fact, that my Bot can't access the avatar of the user, because it doesn't share the same server/guild as this user.

Is there any workaround I could use?

Comment: `console.log(event.user.uid)`, and `console.log(client.users)` and post back here.

Comment: This will return my ID and then a collection of me, Clyde and my Dev-Bot.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question with the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Discord.js and their way of caching, not all users are going to be cached in the bot. While there is a small possibility of it actually not knowing anything about the user, there is a large chance that the Discord API will still allow you to get information from it.

To fix this issue with caching *in the latest master*, we have to use Client.users, which returns a [UserStore](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/UserStore). Within the UserStore, we can use a method called [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/UserStore?scrollTo=fetch) to get information about a user.

To fix this issue *in the latest stable*, we have to use a method called Client.[fetchUser](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser), which does the same thing but returns a User instead of a UserStore.

Please note this is only available using a bot account. Here's an example of its usage:

```
// Using Discord.js Stable
bot.fetchUser(theUsersID).then(myUser => {
    console.log(myUser.avatarURL); // My user's avatar is here!
});

// Using Discord.js Master
bot.users.fetch(theUsersID).then(myUser => {
    console.log(myUser.avatarURL()); // My user's avatar is here!
});
```

If there is an error fetching the user (say, a DiscordAPI Permissions Error), this means that there is no way for your bot to get the user's avatar without knowing who the user is first (or sharing a Guild with the user). Happy coding!